# VSCode's command callback in an extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

We tried to execute VSCode's `Organize imports` command like this: `vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.organizeImports')` and it executes successfully: in a test file we see that imports have been ordered and the file is not saved.

We would like to write an extension that further formats/orders/sorts the imports, so we wanted to write our code in a callback of `executeCommand`, like this:

```
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
  const sortDisposable = vscode.commands.registerTextEditorCommand(SORT_EXTENSION_ID, (editor: vscode.TextEditor) => {
    // execute VS Code's Organize imports command
    return vscode.commands
      .executeCommand('editor.action.organizeImports')
      .then(_ => {
        const content: string = editor.document.getText();
        console.log(`contet`, content)
      }, _ => console.log(`failure`));
  });

  context.subscriptions.push(sortDisposable);
}
```

However, `editor.document.getText()` actually returns the state of the document before the VS Code's `Organize imports` has organized imports.
In other words, the callback that we provided is not executed after VSCode's `Organize imports`.

We also tried [this suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10534#issuecomment-239793355), but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to get a true callback from VSCode, after it has executed a command? According to [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/master/contentprovider-sample/src/provider.ts#L49) (from the VSCode's team itself) it is possible to do, but for some reason it's not working for us.
Is it because we are calling a VSCode's internal method? Does someone have a suggestion what can we do here?

Answer (score 1):

`editor.action.organizeImports` isn't listed as an option within executeCommand docs [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api-commands), so that could be the source of your problems. I'm not sure how to refactor the `vscode.commands.registerTextEditorCommand` parameters, but you could try converting your function to an async/await one:

```
export async function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
  ...
    await vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.organizeImports');
    const content: string = editor.document.getText();
  ...
}
```

This works successfully when I used `vscode.commands.executeCommand(vscode.openFolder, args)`. You could then experiment with `const var = await vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.organizeImports')` to see if `var` is populated with anything useful for you to process.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. The VSCode's command wasn't even called.